# upload file with Jquery-Ajax not working correctly

Tags: jquery, file-upload

i have 3 file in directory.

> 1- jquery-1.8.3.min.js
>
> 2- index.html
>
> 3- addFile.php

and `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` is main jquery file.
`index.html` code is :

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#uploadbutton").click(function () {
                        var filename = $("#tmppic").val();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "addFile.php",
                            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                            data: {
                                file: filename
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                alert(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="tmppic" id="tmppic" />
            <input id="uploadbutton" type="button" value="Upload"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and `addFile.php` code is :

```
<?php
    //print_r($_FILES["tmppic"]);
    echo $_FILES["tmppic"]["type"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tmppic"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["tmppic"]["name"]);
?>
```

but this upload file not work.
thanks from helps.

Comment: does the php script have access to write in `uploads/` ?

Comment: does that echo print the filename?

Comment: here check out, Hope you get answer for your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: you might want to check this out http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use jQuery Form Plugin for ajax file upload.

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/